# Devise Invitable destroying users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-invitable

My app uses `devise` and [devise_invitable](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable) to handle invitations. On my new invitations view I have a table that lists all users that have been invited. I want to add a column to delete each listed user. If I understand correctly, the route expects a format that should probably be something like `remove_user_invitation_path(something)` and also that it appears to be an `invitation_token` (an attribute of the `User model`). I just don't know how to insert it into the URL as a format. I'm also not sure if this will delete the user itself or the invitation (* I placed the) given that a user can accept or ignore an invitation, I worry that it will only work for users that have a pending invitation. Any input is appreciated!

```
$ rails routes
remove_user_invitation GET    /users/invitation/remove(.:format) users/invitations#destroy


# users/invitations/new
<% @invited_users.each do |invited| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= invited.email %></td>
    <td><%= link_to "Delete", remove_user_invitation_path, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete this user?" } %></td>
  <tr>
<% end %>

# GET /resource/invitation/remove?invitation_token=abcdef
def destroy
  resource.destroy
  set_flash_message :notice, :invitation_removed if is_flashing_format?
  redirect_to after_sign_out_path_for(resource_name)
end
# What my variable contains
@invited_users = User.where.not(invitation_sent_at: nil)
```

Comment: `remove_user_invitation_path( invitation_token: invited.invitation_token )`

Comment: And yes, destroying an invitation is the same as destroying a user since "invitations" are not a separate resource.

Comment: Thanks @max that makes sense, after trying to delete a user it returns a `No route matches delete`, for some reason the gem ships with the destroy method as a `GET` request and not delete. Am I missing something, should I make a `delete` request for that same action? Or is there more to that action being GET?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly why it's implemented as GET. I would create an issue on github and ask the author.

Comment: @max, you got any resolution on this? delete method wont work as route is configured for get method.